# How to share by UIActivityController?

Tags: ios, swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've created `@IBAction` with `UIActivityViewController`.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let text1 = "Перевод величины Годы в количестве \(year) лет."
        let text2 = "Месяцы: \(mounthLabel.text!)"
        let text3 = "Недели: \(weekLabel.text!)"
        let text4 = "Дни: \(dayLabel.text!)"
        let text5 = "Часы: \(hourLabel.text!)"
        let text6 = "Минуты: \(minuteLabel.text!)"
        let text7 = "Секунды: \(secundLabel.text!)"
        let URL0 = "Скачать конвертер величин по ссылке:"
        let URL = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unit-converter/id1329406653?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8"
        let space = ""
        let space2 = ""


        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text1, space, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, space2, URL0, URL], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Все замечательно работает, однако при экспорте в приложение штатное "Заметки" сохраняет только первую строку text1. Что может быть не так и есть ли способ это исправить?

It's working, but when i try share to "Notes" or "Facebook" shares only first text1 String. Whats wrong?

Comment: Why not build a single string and share that?

Comment: @rmaddy Because i want to make more accurate and readable export text

Comment: Why wouldn't it be accurate and readable as a single text value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not putting it together to a single text? Something like:

```
let text = "Перевод величины Годы в количестве \(year) лет.\n\nМесяцы: \(mounthLabel.text!)\nНедели: \(weekLabel.text!)\nДни: \(dayLabel.text!)\nЧасы: \(hourLabel.text!)\nМинуты: \(minuteLabel.text!)\nСекунды: \(secundLabel.text!)\n\nСкачать конвертер величин по ссылке:\nhttps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unit-converter/id1329406653?l=ru&ls=1&mt=8"
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: \n\n means a new line?

Comment: @IvanKisin \n is a new line, \n\n are two new lines, I guessed you would want that

Comment: In other words, using two \n gives you one blank line between the two lines of text.